# How to disable 'A new version of DivX is available' pop-up?

Tags: macos, software-update, notifications, mediaplayer

Everyday I see the annoying popup message in the upper right corner saying:

> A new version of DivX is available
>
> Update Now / What's New

[image: A new version of DivX is available - Update Now / What's New]

I'm closing it using *X* button, but it's appearing again after some short time (every ~10-15 minutes), so it's very annoying. It's basically forcing me the upgrade which I don't want to do currently. Either I don't want to uninstall it (however it's the last resort).

Is there any way to disable that kind of popup? Or ignore it for the next few weeks?

Comment: I've added an answer on the original question, see if that helps you.

Comment: My question is about removing the notification it-self, not the software. I want the software, so I need only to ignore the update notification. Secondly your answer doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: I suppose that is the difference between your question and the duplicate. Removing the notification might be as simple as disabling it through DivX preferences (most apps should have a "regularly check for updates" option). I don't use DivX, so I'm not sure. Secondly, please let me know how my answer failed to answer the question, so that I can improve it.

Comment: You simply didn't answer how to disable it, but how to find `divx` in the root folder (what if it's not called `DivX`, but divx player, update helper, or something else). I'd like to answer to my own-answer, but it won't suit to the other which where OP says he doesn't want the software at all.

Comment: Actually, `find` with the `iname` option finds anything matching the pattern - in this case with search query `divx`, results including `divx`, `divxplayer`, `divxhelper` etc. As for your concern about `update helper` these should be in a folder called `divx`, no? That is why I told the OP to "deal with the results accordingly".